# Eclipse Code Visualizer

Tags: eclipse, code-visualization

Is there code visualizer available (preferred as eclipse plugin)?

Comment: You should specify what programming languages you use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/), the code exploration and visualization plugin for Eclipse. It is available for [Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java) and [PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php). nWire analyzes your code in real-time and presents all the components and associations of your code.

Comment: This is a good tool, but is a paid version. you can get a free trial